# Hg select file based on status?

Tags: mercurial, diff, fileset

Is there a way to select only those files that have the Modified status?
And is it possible to chain the selection to add more specific selectors?

I want to export the changes in those **Modified** files, revert to a changeset before I installed the plugin, and re-import changes.

hg diff -I with pattern matching could help, but in this case, and very often, I just want to select files based on their status.

Example of hg st (actual content varies with different folder and filenames/extension):

```
M /readme.txt
M /dir1/somefile1.txt
M /dir2/somefile2.txt
M /dir3/somefile3.txt
M /dir4/somefile4.txt
! /plugin/lotsoffileshere.txt
! /plugin/lotsoffileshere.txt
! /plugin/lotsoffileshere.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read about filesets in mercurial: `hg help filesets`

If you want get diff for all modified files (`hg diff FILE1 FILE2 ... FILE`), build filest for "modified files in repo" in will be (only help was used)

`hg diff "set:modified()"`